# Rest template fail sending apple verification data

Tags: ios, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm trying to validate from apple inapp purchase api using rest template and it fails. (works fine in postman). Postman collection: [collection postman](https://www.getpostman.com/collections/ff834957471c0293ef16)

How I can archive this using rest template? Is base64 encored data not allowed ?

` HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
       // httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        //httpHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

```
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    map.add(Constant.PURCHASE.RECEIPT_DATA, purchase.getReceiptData());

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, httpHeaders);

    ResponseEntity<String> postResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity(iosPurchaseService, request, String.class);`
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Its sorted when we used below answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a object with following property to send the value you need to provide as the input of your API call instead of providing it in a MultiValueMap.

```
public class SomeObject implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@JsonProperty("receipt-data")
private String receiptdata;

}
```

Then bind this object inside your controller as follows.

```
public void apiCall(@RequestBody SomeObject someObject) {

//Method 1
ResponseEntity<String> response1 = restTemplate.postForEntity("https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt", someObject, 
    String.class);
// or Method 2
ResponseEntity<String> response2 = restTemplate.exchange("https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt", HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(someObject, null),
    String.class);

}
```